# setting an integer pointer to an integer array and passing arguments to pthread_create

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers

First, I'm not sure how to set an integer pointer to an array. Second, is this the proper way to set pthread_create arguments?

Here's my argument struct:

```
typedef struct args {
    int *arr;
    int number;
} args;
```

I created a pointer to the struct:

```
args *arguments = (args *)malloc(sizeof(args));
```

I need to set each element of args.arr to argv (command line argument) as an integer. I don't quite understand how to set each element of args.arr:

```
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    arguments->arr[i] = atoi(argv[i]); // Edit: Segmentation fault on this line
```

I created an array of threads:

```
pthread_t threads[4];
```

..and pass the arguments to each function call:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, func, arguments);
```

Comment: Please don't say "this doesn't work" without saying *what* doesn't work. It's utterly unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is an int pointer, so you need to allocate it first:

```
arguments->arr = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
```

Then you can assign properly:

```
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    arguments->arr[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like you have initialized the value of `arguments->arr` to point at a valid `int`.